# Modal at different route in react-router v6 that uses the Navigate component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-triggering-route-d4w9dq?file=/src/App.tsx) that recreates the problem.

I am using the [modal example](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/examples/modal/src/App.tsx) in the react-router v6 source, and I want to display the contents of a route in the modal.

I have my routes defined like this:

```
<Routes location={state?.backgroundLocation || location}>
  <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
    <Route index element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="gallery/:counter" element={<Gallery />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<NoMatch />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>

{/* Show the modal when a `backgroundLocation` is set */}
{state?.backgroundLocation && (
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/modal/:counter" element={<Modal />} />
  </Routes>
)}
```

And when the user clicks the `Modal` link, I want to display the contents of the `gallery/:counter` route in the modal, but I'm not sure how to trigger the route apart from using the `<Navigate />` component, which causes the whole page to redirect.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "redirect just the modal and not the whole page"? The `Navigate` component issues a declarative navigation that takes effect immediately when the component is rendered. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want the modal at a different route than the parent page.

I want to trigger the route in the Modal without redirecting the whole page if that makes sense.

Comment: No, not exactly. Are you wanting to display some nested route content in the modal content? Would it be helpful to us if we could see a more complete [mcve] of the parent page and what the routes look like overall, and what sorts of values `taskUrl` takes?

Comment: @DrewReese I have updated the question and here is a codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-triggering-route-d4w9dq?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Ok, i see, you can't match/render 2 *different* routes at the same time, but are you basically just wanting the `Gallery` component rendered as content in the `Modal`, right?

Comment: @DrewReese that is the problem I have and I'm not sure if there is an answer

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Something like this? https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-triggering-route-forked-0rjhzw?file=/src/App.tsx If so, I can provide an answer with writeup and explanation. Alternatively, does the modal even need to be coupled to a route? It seems you want to display the modal when there is some passed route "state" for a background location. Do you want `"/gallery/:counter"` always rendered in a modal, or just conditionally if the route state exists?

Comment: @DrewReese the problem is that the route is created as part of a framework `backstage` so the route already exists and I don't have access to the component at that route.  I literally need to somehow trigger the route

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251894/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-dagda1).

Comment: @DrewReese I think your answer is good and if you answer with that codesandbox then I will give you the answer

Comment: my requirements are probably a bit obscure but you answered well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't match two *different* URL paths at the same time, the browser has just the one address bar and URL. What I'd suggest is to create a layout route component that wraps the `"/gallery/:counter"` route and conditionally renders the nested route into the `Modal` component.

Example:

```
const ModalLayout = () => {
  const { state } = useLocation();

  return state?.backgroundLocation ? (
    <Modal>
      <Outlet />
    </Modal>
  ) : (
    <Outlet />
  );
};
```

The `Modal` is updated to take a `children` prop and render `children` *as* the modal content. This is where the `Outlet` above is rendered so the nested routes can render their `element` content into the modal.

```
function Modal({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const buttonRef = useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null);

  function onDismiss() {
    navigate(-1);
  }

  return (
    <Dialog
      aria-labelledby="label"
      onDismiss={onDismiss}
      initialFocusRef={buttonRef}
    >
      <div
        style={{
          display: "grid",
          justifyContent: "center",
          padding: "8px 8px"
        }}
      >
        {children}
        <button
          style={{ display: "block" }}
          ref={buttonRef}
          onClick={onDismiss}
        >
          Close
        </button>
      </div>
    </Dialog>
  );
}
```

The `"/gallery/:counter"` route is wrapped in the `ModalLayout` layout route.

```
<Route element={<ModalLayout />}>
  <Route path="gallery/:counter" element={<Gallery />} />
</Route>
```

To make the `counter` state easier to share between routed components, and also persist while switching between home and gallery routes, I suggest moving the `counter` state from the `Home` component into another layout route that provides `counter` state and setter to descendent components via its `Outlet` context.

```
const CounterLayout = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1);

  return <Outlet context={{ counter, setCounter }} />;
};
```

This wraps all the routes that want/need/care for the `counter` state, e.g. the `Home` and `Gallery` components.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
    <Route element={<CounterLayout />}>
      <Route index element={<Home />} />
      <Route element={<ModalLayout />}>
        <Route path="gallery/:counter" element={<Gallery />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="*" element={<NoMatch />} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

[image: Edit modal-at-different-route-in-react-router-v6-that-uses-the-navigate-component (forked)]

[image]
[image]
[image]